# How to compare two pairs of integers in two separate objects?

Tags: java, methods

I have a program in progress that creates two "dominoes", of randomly generated integers `end1` and `end2`. `[end1 | end2]` is the output of the "domino". I am trying to write a method that checks to see whether two Dominoes are the same. I want this method, `equals()`, to compare this Domino to the Domino passed as a parameter. For example `[4|2]` would be equal to `[2|4]`. I'm not sure how to compare the integers in two objects that are created in a different class. I'm sorry if this isn't clear, I will be happy to answer any questions to help. Thanks so much!

so far, I have

```
public boolean equals(Domino d) {
    return (this.end1 && this.end2 == Domino.end1 && Domino.end2 ? true : false);
}
```

Clearly, this is very wrong syntactically, but conceptually, it's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare the first end of one Domino to the first end of the other, and the second end of the first to the second end of the other. If they don't both match, you compare the first end of one to the second end of the other and vice versa.

```
public boolean equals(Domino d) {
    if (this.end1 == d.end1 && this.end2 == d.end2)
        return true;
    if (this.end2 == d.end1 && this.end1 == d.end2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little simpler and easier to read:

```
public boolean equals(Domino d) {
  if ((this.end1 == d.end1 && this.end2 == d.end2) ||
      (this.end2 == d.end1 && this.end1 == d.end2)) 
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }   
}
```

Just think about what you wanna do in English:

> IF
>
> this end1 and Domino's end1 are the same 
>   AND
>   this end2 and Domino's end2 are the same
>
> OR
>
> this end2 and Domino's end1 are the same
>   AND
>   this end1 and Domino's end2 are the same
>
> RETURN true
>
> ELSE
>
> RETURN false

That normally makes it easier to think about how to set the conditions

Comment: `Domino.end1` won't compile, since `end1` is most likely not a static member (otherwise this method has no point).

Comment: @Eran I noticed it right before your comment and just fixed. Do you mind removing the -1?